# How to extract <pre> within <div> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='Thirdsamplecodesnippet' class='clearfix'>
<pre class='brush:html;'>&lt;html&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Hello world.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</pre>
<input type='hidden' id='codeid' value='process'>  
</div>
```

I would like to extract this from the div:

```
<pre class='brush:html;'>&lt;html&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Hello world.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</pre>
```

How is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html of parent `div` with id `Thirdsamplecodesnippet` is is what you need. You can use id [**selector**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) of jQuery to get the parent div jQuery object and call [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function on it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4EnCt/)**

```
$('#Thirdsamplecodesnippet').html()
```

Comment: I forgot I have a hidden field too within the div. How to isolate only the <pre> section? Thanks for the quick answer.